# Charging url images in cache with Picasso without target (ImageView)

Tags: android, caching, picasso

At the first launch of my application, I recovered urls of my images from my webservice.

Also, I would like to cache them with Picasso (and display them in a second time) but this doesn't seems to work.

This is my code :

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(myUrl).fetch();
```

Maybe I don't understand the use of fetch method, also I logged my url, they're valid.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what does not work?

Comment: If I close the connection after fetch my urls, when I switch to another fragment which load images from the same url it doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(myUrl).into(new Target() {

  @Override
  public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap arg0, LoadedFrom arg1) {
    // if you want to save your bitmap to sdcard you can do it here                                 
  }

  @Override
  public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {

  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Does it work with any folder ? Picasso can automatically find the file with a simple Picasso.with(mContext).load(myUrl).into(myImageView) ?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, the url gived by my webservice was not the same as the object url returned.
I switched on Universal Image Loader between this and it works now.